How to give a quotient map?
Show that the cone $(^,_{^}
 )$ is homeomorphic to $(\overline{}^{+1} ,_)$, $(Σ^,_{Σ^}
 )$ is homeomorphic to $(^{+1},_{^{+1}}
 )$ for  ∈ ℕ.

I know there is a theorem,if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a quotient map,then the quotient sapce $X/ ~$is homeomorphic to Y.While I don't know how to give a quotient map for general $n$.
Thank you for any help.

Could you give a little more detail/ clarity. Maybe introduce your notations? I suppose $\Sigma$ is the suspension ? Tell us how you define it and how you define the cone

Ok, I edited it again.

I think these have been asked before

I suggest you try to do it for $n=1$ in order to get the right thing, then do my proof (but verify the assumptions of quotient topology, I was lazy).

For the first homeo, consider the continuous, surjective map
$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
\psi: &\mathbb{S}^n \times I &\to& \mathbb{D}^{n+1}\\
&(x,t) & \mapsto & t\cdot x
\end{array}$$
It is injective on $(\mathbb{S}^n \times I)\setminus (\mathbb{S}^n \times \{0\})$.
Applying your theorem, you get $C \mathbb{S}^n =(\mathbb{S}^n \times I)/ (\mathbb{S}^n \times \{0\}) \cong \mathbb{D}^{n+1}$

The cone gives you the suspension: you already know that $C\mathbb{S}^n \cong \bar{\mathbb{D}}^{n+1}$. You probably already know that $\bar{\mathbb{S}}^{n+1} \cong \bar{\mathbb{D}}^{n+1}/\partial \bar{\mathbb{D}}^{n+1}$, now since homeomorphism commute with $\partial$, you get:
$$C\mathbb{S}^n / \partial C\mathbb{S}^n \cong \bar{\mathbb{D}}^{n+1}/\partial \bar{\mathbb{D}}^{n+1} \cong \mathbb{S}^{n+1}$$
But $\partial C\mathbb{S}^n = \mathbb{S}^n \times \{1\}$ so you get
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{S}^{n+1} &\cong C\mathbb{S}^n/(\mathbb{S}^n \times \{1\}) \cong ((\mathbb{S}^n \times I)/(\mathbb{S}^n \times \{0\}))/(\mathbb{S}^n \times \{1\}) \\
&\cong (\mathbb{S}^n \times I)/(\mathbb{S}^n \times \{0\} \sqcup \mathbb{S}^n \times \{1\}) = \Sigma\mathbb{S}^n 
\end{align*}$$

Now we can also construct a direct homeo from $\Sigma \mathbb{S}^n$ to $\mathbb{S}^{n+1}$; consider:
$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
\phi: &\mathbb{S}^n \times [-1,1] &\to& \mathbb{S}^{n+1}\\
&((x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}),t) & \mapsto & (\sqrt{1-t^2}\cdot x_1,\dots,\sqrt{1-t^2} \cdot x_{n+1},t)
\end{array}$$
Using your theorem (since it is surjective and continuous), the only non-trivial fibers are at $(0,\dots,0,1) $ and $(0,\dots,0,-1) $ so we get:
$$\mathbb{S}^{n+1} \cong (\mathbb{S}^n \times [-1,1]) /(\mathbb{S}^n \times \{-1\} \sqcup \mathbb{S}^n \times \{1\}) \cong \Sigma \mathbb{S}^n$$ (I used the obvious homeo from $I$ to $[-1,1]$.)

Now if you wish to understand it, draw it for $n=1$.

Here is the theorem you were mentioning:

If $X$ and Y are topological spaces, a map $\pi : X \to Y$ is called a quotient map if it is surjective and continuous and $Y$ has the quotient topology determined by $\pi$.
The fiber of $π$ over a point $y ∈ Y$ is the set $\pi^{−1}(y)$.
Open sets must verify: $U = \pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$ for Y to have the quotient topology.
The quotient space is the quotient of $X$ by all its fibers (of course only the non trivial one are meaningful).


Thank you,these two maps are impressive ! I even can't imagine how did you get the idea of constructing them,thank you again.

Draw them for $n=1$ this will become very clear, basically the first one gives the disk as concentric circles and the second one gives the sphere in slices of circle on top of each other. Remove the poles of your sphere and you have a homeo

Also be careful, the border is easy to compute since $\partial \mathbb{S}^n = \emptyset$, in general it is a bit more complicated

Thank you.I will check them  tomorrow,everything you wrote is helpful for me,I am a new student now studying general topology.
